# PureData crashing with pigpio

Tags: pigpio, puredata

This morning, I wrote a very quick [external](https://github.com/nullpainter/pigpio_mcp3008) for PureData which allows it to read from an MCP3008 via pigpio.

This works well until the DAC is enabled, upon which PureData almost immediately crashes with an ALSA error:

```
restart alsa output
alsa xrun recovery apparently failed
pd: pcm.c:1168: snd_pcm_prepare: Assertion `pcm' failed.
2021-09-05 21:23:19 sigHandler: Unhandled signal 6, terminating
```

Looking at [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39963/pigpio-pwm-and-alsa) which suggested a possible cause, I added `gpioCfgClock(5, 0, 0);` before `gpioInitialise()`. When this is in place, PureData doesn't crash but I can only hear what sounds like a stream of data through the in-built headphone jack.

I am using CS 25, MISO 6, MOSI 16 and SCLK 5.

This is a mostly bog-standard Raspbian install. Also, I should be receiving a USB audio device soon - not sure if that will magically make the problem go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/faq.html#Sound_isnt_working

> Sound isn't working
>
> The Pi contains two pieces of hardware, a PWM peripheral and a PCM
> peripheral, to generate sound.  The PWM peripheral is normally used
> and generates medium quality audio out of the headphone jack.  The PCM
> peripheral may be used by add-ons such as HATs and generates high
> quality audio.
>
> pigpio uses at least one of these peripherals during normal operation
> (for timing DMA transfers).  pigpio will use both peripherals if waves
> or the hardware PWM function is used.
>
> By default pigpio uses the PCM peripheral leaving the PWM peripheral
> free for medium quality audio.
>
> You can change the default with a configuration option.  For C use
> gpioCfgClock, for the pigpio daemon use the -t option.

If you can't resolve the problem with pigpio and the only use for pigpio is SPI I suggest you use (my) [lg library](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/) instead.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think to look at your FAQ. Unfortunately I'm rather relying on pigpio's bit banging functions as I have two MCP2008's and two port expanders that need to be connected. I'll be trying the Patchbox distribution shortly anyway; will be interested to see if this changes anything.

Comment: Patchbox, using JACK, doesn't result in PureData crashing but does result in choppy audio. Marginally better...

Comment: Cheap USB audio device arrived today. Curiously, PWM vs PCM made no difference to the output - both resulted in choppy audio via Jack. Then I realised that I had the baud set very low for `bbSPIOpen()`. Upping it to 250000 did the trick.

(Is this a filthy hack? Has my audio been imperceptibly degraded as a result?)